# How to convert the Node.js date format to oracle datetime format from configuration

Tags: node.js, oracle, date-format

I need change de DATEFORMAT from Oracle db without change Querys, I was work with postgres and pg module in NodeJS have types to parse the format that response me the module before make query calls, but I search the same way to config this in oracle but i can not find how

oracle dateformat

2009-01-01T05:00:00.000Z

i need this dateformat

01-01-2009 05:00:00" / "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss

I use oracledb package from npm to make the conexion between nodejs and oracle

Comment: How are you getting the date from the Oracle database? If it's a query, can you share the query you are using to get the date?

Comment: Yes is a query, but i need no change the queries, there are many queries, i know how change the format into SQL,but i need chage the format inside the sql connection or some like that

Comment: See [Working with Dates Using the Node.js Driver](https://jsao.io/2016/09/working-with-dates-using-the-nodejs-driver/)  - and check the node-oracledb documentation

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default date format that is returned by altering the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` for your session.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format="DD-MON-YYYY";

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

       SYSDATE
______________
24-SEP-2020

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format="DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS";

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

               SYSDATE
______________________
24-09-2020 15:02:57
```

Comment: Since running an ALTER for each connection is expensive, one alternative includes setting NLS_DATE_FORMAT (and NLS_LANG) before starting Node.js.  Another way with a connection pool is to execute the ALTER in a sessionCallback - check the node-oracledb doc.